# How to use Bazel to crate a wheel file for a package that build with cmake

Tags: bazel, python-wheel

I have a made a python package. The package is currently build using cmake. I want to prebuild this package on my laptop and create a .whl file, such that I can install it on other platform without worrying about building.

I know that bazel could do it. Can someone help me with an example or is there any other tools to prebuild a package that build with Cmake into wheel file?